# Do you read the 'c' in 'kc'?

Tags: pronunciation, compounds

For example:

- clickcub
- clickcube
- clickcrab
- clickcrate
- clickcone

In which of those cases do you read the 'c' and not?

Comment: Tricky to impose a pronunciation rule on made-up compounds, but the real-world example of the same problem (*bookkeeping*) has the *k* sounds run together with the glottal stop or geminate (see below), so I suggest that follows here in the absence of anything to the contrary.

Comment: Another real-world example: stock car (spelled as two words, but used as a compound word).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is difficult to answer without referring to phonetic details, but I'll do the best I can.

All of the words that you mentioned are compounds (and new, unfamiliar compounds at that), which will be pronounced with a *geminate* `[k]` in careful speech. For example, your "clickcub" would be something like `['klɪk:ʰʌb]`. Two consecutive /k/ sounds run together as a geminate or "long" `[k]`. Whether you perceive this as one /k/ or two has more to do with your native language than with English phonetics.

I'm not aware of *any* dialect of English where you pronounce these words with two distinct releases, as `[kʰkʰ]`. Furthermore, in rapid speech even the geminates will be shortened, rendering all of them as a single `[k]`.

Comment: Is there a difference in careful speech between *clickrate* and *clickcrate*? As in something like "I pushed up the clickrate" (increased the rate of clicking) compared with "I pushed up the clickcrate" (elevated the crate designed for clicks)?

Comment: @Henry: Yes, *clickrate* has a short *k* sound while *clickcrate* would typically have a long (geminate) one.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: So I would take your answer to be "Yes, English does adjust the pronunciation for the c in the kc examples shown."

Comment: @Henry Even if the pronunciation were rapid and slurred enough that the geminate /k:/ were degeminated to just /k/, _click crate_ would be different in that the following /r/ would still be unvoiced. In _click rate_, it would be voiced.