# Pronunciation of double consonants

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, doubled-consonants

How do you pronounce double consonants in American English?

For example:

- Daddy -  Do you say "Da-di", "Dad-di" or "Dad-i"?
- Mommy - Do you say "Ma-mi", "Mam-mi" or "Mam-i"?
- Swimming - "swi-ming", "swim-ming" or "swim-ing"?

I try to listen but I can’t catch it. Are there any rules to pronounce double consonants?

By the way, I'd to know more about syllabic-boundary of double consonants.
For example, I read two dictionaries online. For "Mommy" one pronounces "Ma-mi" and another one pronounces "Mam-i". It makes me confused. Can we say both?
But when I hear by myself it looks like "Mam-mi", can I say that too?

And about "butter" (it's interesting) which EnabledZombie wrote that it is pronounced "budder" (two Ds) but I saw in a dictionary, it wrote that it has to be pronounced "bud.er". There is only one D. How are they different? Or does it share "d" between 2 syllabics?

Comment: I corrected your question formatting, so it's easier to read now. :) (If you don't like it, you can roll back or re-edit in some other way.)

Comment: Related: [Pronunciation of “applicable”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11427/pronunciation-of-applicable)

Comment: Related: [Different syllabic boundaries in various dictionaries](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21529/different-syllabic-boundaries-in-various-dictionaries).  [Neil Coffey's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21529/different-syllabic-boundaries-in-various-dictionaries/21557#21557) even mentions a doubled consonant when discussing hypenation.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your help.Right now I understand more about double consonant and syllabics.Moreover,Thanks for edition,Rhodri. I like it.:-)You're really kind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To expand on the other answers, you will find that some American English pronunciation of consonants is different from that of British English. For example, the *Ts* in *butter* are pronounced distinctly as *Ts* in the UK (*buht-er*), but just the same as *Ds* in America (*buh-der*). Note that both of these pronunciations use only one consonant sound, not two.

An audial example can be heard at 01:52 in [this video](http://www.videojug.com/film/how-to-do-an-american-accent).

Comment: Yes, but Americans pronounce the 't' in *butter* in the same way that we pronounce the 't' in *waiter.* It has **nothing** to do with the fact that the consonant is doubled.

Comment: In case anyone else is confused, the Ts in _butter_ are only pronounced as _one_ T in British English (and likewise _one_ D in some varieties of American English)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Peter and Rhodri. I've altered my contribution based on your feedback.

Comment: The UK RP pronunciation of *butter* is [ˈbʌtə]; the North American pronunciation is [ˈbʌɾɝ]. Intervocalic t’s like that always reduce to a simple flap in North America. Also, unlike say Italian, English has no geminated consonants, even when written doubled. Compare Italian *bella* /ˈbɛl.la/ with English *Bella* /ˈbɛlə/.

Comment: Besides cases where the collision of consonants in compound, prefixed or suffixed words cause doubling [I offer as examples 'midday', 'unnecessary' and 'solely'], doubling also occurs in some varieties of British English in very specific circumstances: when a stressed vowel is followed by an unvoiced consonant, then one of /l/, /r/, /w/ or /j/.  Thus, 'Zeppelin' pronounced /ˈzɛpplɪn/, 'mattress' pronounced /ˈmattɹəs/, 'liquid' pronounced /ˈlɪkkwɪd/ and 'executive' pronounced /ɪgˈzɛkkjətɪv/.  I concede that each doubling might be  regarded as glottal stop + single consonant.

Answer (score 7):

In English, double consonants and single consonants are two ways of spelling the same sound; unlike Italian, this difference in spelling does not indicate any sound difference. There are compound words such as *bookkeeper* where "double consonants" are indeed pronounced differently from single ones, but none of your examples are in this category; see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15157/do-you-read-the-c-in-kc).

Comment: What about the word **accent**, for example? Don't you pronounce both c's?

Comment: @Bruno You say "Aksent" not "akkent" so it's not a double consonant like the italian word "Casa" vs "Cassa".

Answer (score 6):

In general, doubling a consonant in English doesn't affect how the consonant is pronounced (unlike, say, Finnish).  If it has any effect at all, it is usually to shorten the vowel before it, as in "hoping" and "hopping" (/həʊpiŋ/ and /hɒpiŋ/ respectively), which is related to the ["silent e"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_e) spelling convention.

There are exceptions, most of which have grown up through historical accident.  All the examples that have sprung to mind are occasions where "cc" has become pronounced /ks/ for some reason: *accelerate*, *accent*, *access* and so on.

There are also a number of double consonants that aren't really double consonants, where one or other consonant is actually part of a [digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_%28orthography%29) with a completely different sound.  @psmears kindly supplied *outthink* and *misshapen* as examples; there are undoubtedly more out there.

Comment: As @Bruno suggested above, **accent**.

Comment: @MT_Head: All of the other ones I can think of are "cc" pronounced as /ks/ too: _accident_, _accede_, _access_...

Comment: @MT_Head @Rhodri "_Account_"?

Comment: @Alenanno @Rhodri - Yes, "account" seems like a good exception to the apparent "cc" rule...  Excuse me; I'm off to work out an accord with my aksountant.

Comment: "outthink"? "misshapen"? Or is that cheating? :-)

Comment: @psmears - per @Rhodri's post ("where one or other consonant is actually part of a digraph with a completely different sound") I'd say that _we_ were cheating and you played it straight.

Comment: @psmears: many thanks for those examples, that's exactly what I was trying to think of.

Comment: @MT_Head: this is looking a bit like the rules for pronouncing "c" in Italian: /tʃ/ if followed by "i" or "e", otherwise /k/.  I'd hazard a guess that here we have "cc" pronounced /ks/ if followed by "i" or "e", otherwise /k/.  I feel a question coming on...

Comment: The "cc" in "accent" is actually two separate graphemes: Hard C + Soft C = /ks/.  But "cc" in "account" is a double hard C = /kk/ = /k/.

Comment: The example in Peter Shor's answer, for _bookkeeper_ provides an interesting case. In compound words, doubled consonants across the word boundary can lead to a [geminate consonant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination), such as /ˈbʊkːɪpɚ/