# Origins of English Double-C Pronunciations

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, history, doubled-consonants

Looking into [Pronunciation of double consonants](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29059/pronunciation-of-double-consonants), turned up an apparent rule for pronouncing a double-C in English that seems to parallel the Italian rule for pronouncing a single C.  If the "cc" is followed by a bright vowel ("i" or "e"), it is pronounced /ks/:

> accent, occipital, eccentric

Otherwise it is pronounced /k/:

> account, occasion, occupy

A dictionary search throws up a few exceptions to this, which mostly appear to be musical loan words from Italian which are still pronounced as the in original ("acciaccatura" for example).

The question is this: how did this rule come about?  The parallel with Italian is close enough to make me very suspicious, but I haven't been able to prove a connection between the two.

Comment: Doesn't this directly follow from the rules of pronouncing `c`'s?

Comment: Your analogy with Italian doesn't work very well I'm afraid. Single `c`s in Italian are often pronounced with a `ch` sound. Double `c`s in Italian are often pronunced as "hard" `c`s.

Comment: In fact, the only other language I know of that shares this pronounciation rule is French, so I suspect the root lies there (more naturally too)!

Comment: @Noldorin: whether the C is doubled or not isn't relevant to Italian pronunciation as I learned it.  It's the following letter that matters: bright vowels mean `ch`, everything else `k`.  That's why "ch" in Italian seems odd to English speakers: the H is inserted purely to stop the next letter being a bright vowel.

Comment: @trutheality: you should make that an answer and provide some references!

Comment: The rule in italian is the following: _K sounds_ (Ca, co, cu), _C sound_ (like cherry) (ce, ci). To make them the opposite, you must add **i** to the first series and **h** to the second. So: (Cia, cio, ciu) and (che, chi).

Comment: @Rhodri: I was told this once, but it wasn't by a native speaker, so could well be wrong. Alenanno is exactly correct in his answer. Trust a native Italian. :-) Perhaps he can explain what happens with double-`c`s too...

Comment: So whats Zucchini's excuse?

Comment: @Unkwntech: Americans :-)  In the Italian it would be pronounced /zukini/ (modulo getting the vowels right), and that's how I pronounce it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgetting about the "doubling" of the consonant for a second, in English, some consonants, most notably `c` and `g`, but also `s`, `t`, `x`, and the pairs `ch` and `th` are softened when followed by softening vowels (usually `i` and `e` are the softening vowels, but `a` and `io` soften `t`, `s`, and `a` softens `x` for example).

> Most of the "softenings" originated in Late Latin as a result of either intervocalic voicing or palatalization before front vowels.

- [Emerson, Ralph H. (1997), "English Spelling and Its Relation to Sound"](http://jstor.org/stable/455654)
- Or, if you want a more accessible resource, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_and_soft_C) isn't bad.

**Now what does it have to do with a double `c`?**

Let's look at an example: `eccentric`

The first `c` is followed by a consonant, `c`, so it is pronounced as a `k`, while the second `c` is followed by an `e`, so it is pronounced as an `s`.
Putting those together gives a `ks` sound.

On the other hand, in a word like `occasion`, the second `c` is followed by an `a`, which doesn't soften the `c`. So both `c`s are pronounced as `k`'s, which is in turn pronounced as a single `k` sound.

Answer (score 1):

An exception seems to be *flaccid*, where the "first" pronunciation is -s-.

Comment: After a quick search I found out (to my surprise) that both pronunciations (ks and s) are acceptable for that word. Even though I've never heard the former.

Comment: Comparing 'flaCCid' with 'aCCident', I wondered if the (usual) difference in handling CC is derived from the days when most of those who used 'learned' words were familiar with Latin.  'Accident' can be analysed into 'ac' [modified 'ad' before C] + 'cid' [fall] + 'ent' [present participle].  'Flaccid' is just 'flacc' + 'id'  -  the double C stays together.